# SOQL from a junction record?

Tags: soql, junction-object

Hopefully this is simple to everyone with a bit more experience.  I am trying to retrieve related records with a query. The objects are related via a Junction Object.  I've done quite a bit of searching but haven't found a method to do this

The three objects are: Account, A junction object called CovenantJunction where - Account is master, Covenant is master (LLC_BI__Account_Covenant__c), and Covenant (LLC_BI__Covenant2__c)

How can I get all of the related Covenant records if I have the Account Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Id accountId = ...;

Covenant__c[] covenants = [
        select Id, Name, ...
        from Covenant__c
        where Id in (
                select Covenant__c
                from CovenantJunction__c
                where Account__c = :accountId
        )];
```

Refer to the [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) for more explanation.

Comment: Specifically, look at the **Left Inner Join** section.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fields api name on CovenantJunction is Covenant__c and Account.You can use a query like this:

```
select Covenant__r.name from CovenantJunction where Account='a00P0000003IeLt'
```

Here the last part is the id. If you have it in a variable named accountid ,then you can use:

```
select Covenant__r.name from CovenantJunction where Account=:accountid
```

If there are more than one covenant__c record then you can use a list to store the CovenantJunction and iterate the list to get the covenant__c.

```
List<CovenantJunction> s =[select id,covenant__r.name from CovenantJunction where Account=:accountid];
```